# Mistake in defended PhD thesis

Tags: phd, thesis, ethics, errors-erratum

I have defended my thesis and the PhD was awarded. But now I realize that I have made a mistake. The same images are published for 2 different samples. ( I have  the real two images but somehow 1 was published in both cases). What should I do now? No one has looked into the matter.